# how to convert speech to text using cortana and save that text into text file?

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text, speech-synthesis, cortana, microsoft-speech-platform

I have the application which embedded cortana. i want to do such way that cortana recognize continuously and convert that speech into text . Also it save that text into text file. I do not want actual coding but i want a perfect flow to do this . is there any one who give a flow chart or some links that help me in my project ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure of your question - you currently cannot integrate Cortana into your app via any official API. Do you mean that you are integrating your app into Cortana via VCD?

In any case, you probably want to use the Project Oxford APIs rather than Cortana for your use case. Assuming you have the end user's consent to record their data (which, alarmingly, I do not see you have!), you can use the [Speech to Text API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/mt613445.aspx) to convert the user speech into text, which can then be exported to text using any file IO library. However, without specifics, it's difficult to go into any further detail.

Comment: Thank you . It helps me much .